# Add Product ean13 barcode in Quotation line item search (Odoo 8)

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo, ean-13

I want to know how to proceed for adding in the search a  product by barcode (ean 13) in sale quotations. Like the image here, I have only the name of the product and product internal reference.

[image: screenshot]

I try to override the model product.product like this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, api

class product_product(models.model):

_inherit = "product.product"

def name_search(self, cr, user, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=100):

res = super(product_product, self).name_search(self, cr, user, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=100)

if operator in ('ilike', 'like', '=', '=like', '=ilike'):

domain = [('ean13', operator, name)]

ids = self.search(cr, user, domain, limit=limit, context=context)

res += self.name_get(cr, user, ids, context=context)

return res

self.search([('ean13', 'ilike', name)])
```

Comment: Check if my answer is helpful. If you are not able to achieve what you want let me know

Answer (score 0):

The `name_get` method changes the default name that appears on the drop_down list.

Override the `name_search` method instead, something like this:

```
@api.model
def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    # Make a search with default criteria
    temp = super(models.Model, self).name_search(
        name=name, args=args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
    # Make the other search
    temp += super(ProductProduct, self).name_search(
        name=name, args=args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
    # Merge both results
    res = []
    keys = []
    for val in temp:
        if val[0] not in keys:
            res.append(val)
            keys.append(val[0])
            if len(res) >= limit:
                break
    return res
```

You just need to add the results of the `ean13` as well to the method:

```
self.search([('ean13', 'ilike', name)])
```

Comment: Hi ChesuCR ! I modified the code but it doesn't work...(I modified the code that I wrote in my first question like you told me) How can we resolve that ? Iam working with Odoo 8

Answer (score 0):

you can also write this way

```
def name_search(self, cr, user, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=100):

    res = super(product_product, self).name_search(self, cr, user, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=100)

    if operator in ('ilike', 'like', '=', '=like', '=ilike'):

        domain = [('ean13', operator, name)]

        ids = self.search(cr, user, domain, limit=limit, context=context)
        res+=self.browse(ids).name_get()
        return res
```